# Search DataGridView without using Datasource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Im struggling with a small issue (searching in Datagridview)

I have found a code to do the search function, but the problem is that whenever the function starts, the database is reloaded. (when i follow the binding source rowfilter or the string.format functions), this makes the search function slow, what i need to do is that after i load my database to the DGV, i need to search only on the data in the datagridview, i don't want to use the binding source or to set a new data view.

here is my current code and working ok except that whenever the text is changed the DB loads again.

```
Me.ACCESSIONTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HomeDataSet.ACCESSION)
    Dim dv As New DataView(HomeDataSet.ACCESSION)
    dv.RowFilter = String.Format("AC_NO Like '%{0}%' and ac_receiveddt >= '{1}'  and ac_receiveddt <= '{2}'", TextBox1.Text, DateTimePicker1.Text, DateTimePicker2.Text)
    ACCESSIONDataGridView.DataSource = dv
```

So, is there another way to search the currently populated data in the DGV without using the data source ?

Comment: What do you mean `the database is reloaded`? Fiddling with a control's datasource wont requery the DB unless you have code (event code ?) somewhere that does so. The control will redraw, but thats not the same thing. Also you should be probably be using `DateTimePicker.Value.Date` in the filter (please dont say the dates are stored as text). Finally, please read [Ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data only reloads because you're reloading it.  If you don't want to retrieve data again then don't call `Fill` again.  Call `Fill` once only, to retrieve the data in the first place.  Bind your `DataTable` to your `BindingSource` and your `BindingSource` to your grid.  When you want to filter the data, simply set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.  The text you're assigning to the `RowFilter` of the `DataView` in your code above is what you assign to that `Filter` property.

Comment: Such a stupid thing i forgot to take it out. Deleted that line and it works gracefully ! Thank you very much !!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this

```
Sub display()
    'select query is used to display the list of records from the database to be displayed in the datagridview.
    Dim temp As Double = 0
    Dim lt As String = "select id as ID, vlname as Last, vfname as First, vmname as Middle, vgnd as Gender, vdob as Birthday, iage as Age, vcourse as Course from tbreg where vlname Like '" + tbsearch.Text + "%' or vfname Like '" + tbsearch.Text + "%' order by vlname asc" 'add desc for descending order/ asc for ascending (order by vlanme desc)
    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(lt, con)
    con.Open()

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "tbreg")
    da.Dispose()
    dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Just call the method whenever he clicks a button or when a textchanges in a textbox

Comment: As a typed `DataSet` is being used, you'd have to add a new query to the appropriate table adapter.